# pydev - how to avoid adding sub directories to python path in order to fix unresolved import issue

Tags: python, pydev

My project has root src folder created by pydev project wizard. Src folder is in the project's python path. Underneath that folder I have a package (folder with `__init__.py`) with two files: `a.py` and `b.py`. `b.py` is trying to import from `a.py` but I'm getting the error of unresolved import.

I was able to "fix" error by explicitly adding that subfolder to project's python path as additional src folder. Now I have two folders as src folders in pythonpath. What I don't understand is, why pydev is not able to resolve import since the package/folder I'm talking about is directly underneath root src folder which is in the python path. There are no python files in root src folder.

If I add `__init__.py` to root src folder, the issue is still there. I simply have to add subfolder to pythonpath in order to make error go away.

Am I doing something wrong ? This doesn't seem right.

**EDIT:**
I was wrong. My import syntax was incorrect. I should have done: from **package.module** import someting and not from **module** import something

Comment: As I said in my answer, I think you probably actually want a relative import here—`from .module import something`—rather than an absolute import—`from package.module import something`. They'll both work in most of the same cases, but the relative is clearer, and makes it easier to refactor your package later (e.g., you can rename `package` to `pkg`, and the hundreds of `from .module import something` statements at the start of all of its internal modules still work). But it's your call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your description, and actual code would help, but I suspect what you're looking for is a relative import.

If you have a file `pkg/a.py` that just does this:

```
import b
```

That will look for a top-level module somewhere on your `sys.path` named `b.py`.

But if you do this:

```
from . import b
```

Then it will look within (and *only* within) `pkg` for a file named `b.py`.

---

Alternatively, you could use an absolute import, the same way you would in a module outside the package, like one of these:

```
import pkg.b
from pkg import b
```

---

Your attempted workaround of adding `pkg` to `sys.path` is a very bad idea, for multiple reasons. For example, `b` and `pkg.b` will become different modules as far as Python is concerned, so the top-level code can end up getting run twice, you can end up with two separate copies of all of the globals (and even if you think "I'm not using globals", you probably as—classes and functions are globals, and you can easily end up with a situation where `b.MyClass(3) != pkg.b.MyClass(3)` unexpectedly, which is always fun to debug…), etc.

Adding an `__init__.py` to `src` is also a bad idea. That turns `src` into a package, meaning the proper qualified name for `b` is now `src.pkg.b`, rather than `pkg.b`, but there's no way to import it under the proper name (unless the parent directory of `src` happens to be on `sys.path` as well as `src`… in which case you have the exact same problem as the above paragraph).

---

See [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more details, and the tutorial section on [Packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for a simpler overview.

Comment: I am doing this in b.py: from a import dct, where dct is dictionary and a is a.py file/module. both a.py and b.py are in the same package. When I add that package to python path and restart eclipse, everything works correctly. The problem is that root src folder which contains this package is already in the python path and I'm wondering why pydev can't resolve imports. Should I add every package I create to python path even if the root folder is in the python path already ?

Comment: @IvanDavidov: No. Please read the whole answer, or the tutorial and PEP. You cannot do `from a import dct` for the exact same reason you can't do `import a`. If `a.py` and `b.py` are inside a package directory `pkg`, there is no module named `a`; there's only a module named `pkg.a`. And any workarounds you try to put together to force `a` to be a valid module will break everything.

Comment: I'm going through beginners book on python, I'm not yet at modules/packages part. I know some python so I thought that I knew what I was doing. I get it now -> from pckg.module import something. Excuse me for my impatient response. I will accept this answer and delete the question since it's useless. Thank you.

Comment: @IvanDavidov: I don't think the question is useless; I can imagine other people running into the same problem. When you try to go too far ahead in a book, you end up trying to write code you don't know how to write; there's really no way around that, right?

Comment: Right, for instance, I wrongly assumed that, if two modules are in the same package, I don't need to explicitly mention package name in the import statement... lesson learned, thanks once again.